# Cloud Data Fusion: Numeric datatype into BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap, wrangler

I'm running a Data Fusion pipeline with Wrangler transformations and I want to store a value as Numeric in BigQuery for some precise arithmetic calculations, but Wrangler doesn't let me transform a FLOAT value to NUMERIC.

I've tried with implicit conversion trying to write a FLOAT value into a NUMERIC column inside BQ but that didn't work.

Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the value to a decimal datatype which maps to the bigquery NUMERIC datatype. Documentation [here](https://cdap.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DOCS/pages/464912425/Google+BigQuery+Table+Sink).

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST() function for explicit conversion as it always converts any numeric type to another numeric type.

```
CAST(expression AS NUMERIC)
```

You can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conversion_rules#comparison_chart) for conversion rules and comparison chart.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. I need to convert it to numeric BEFORE it's written to BigQuery, not after it has been written.